# C char array concatenation memory dumped

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, concatenation, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following piece of code :

```
char * set_number(void)
{
    // char * sname = malloc(sizeof(char) * 18); Original
    char * sname = malloc(sizeof(char) * 19); // After EDIT 1
    memset(sname, '\0', 19);                  // After EDIT 1
    strcat(sname, "0x0012345678912345");
    return sname;
}

char * get_number(void)
{
    char * rnumber = set_number();
    return rnumber;
}

char * work_with_number(void)
{
    int i = 7;
    char * wnumber = get_number();
    if(strstr(wnumber, "0x00") != NULL)
    {
        wnumber += 4;
        char c = i + '0';
        // Would like to concatene c at the end of wnumber here
    }
    return wnumber;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char * str = work_with_number();
    fprintf(stdout, "str : %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

returns :

```
str : 12345678912345
```

As write in comment, I want to concatenate `c` into `wnumber`.

However, use `strcat()` begets to a memory dump.

In addition the memory needs to be freed into the main function, not ?

I guess that I still misunderstand the logic here.

Comment: Aside from what Sourav said: Adding 4 to `wnumber` is nice in theory, but now you don't know which memory to free after you call `work_with_number`.

Comment: So, do you suggest to create an other buffer `str = (char *) malloc(strlen(sname)` to store the string `&sname[4]` ?

Comment: yes, but probably `str = malloc(strlen(sname) + 2)`. You need one character for the null terminator and one for the '7' character that you wanted to append. Also, you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc` in c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string starts with a `0x00`, you want to remove that prefix and append a seven instead. There are several problems with your approach, many of which have aldready been addressed by others:

- You must hold on the pointer that you received from `malloc` in order to `free` the memory later.
- There is no room at the end of your string to concatenate anything.
- `strstr` looks for the search string anywhere in your string, but you want to test whether `0x00` is at the beginning. Use `strncmp` for that.
- `strcat` concatenates to zero-terminated strings, but zeroing the memory first and then `strcat`ting is wasteful. `strcpy` to the string directly.

Another approach is to move the rest of the string to the front. This will leave four chars at the end, which you can use to append stuff, but not more than you have removed, of course:

```
before:    0 x 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 \0
                   |                         |
           +-------+                 +-------+
           |                         |
after      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 7 \0
                                       |  |
                                       +--+---- new
```

You can write a loop for this, but there are also two functions in the standard lib for this: `memcpy`, which requires the buffers not to overlap, and `memmove`, which can handle overlapping buffer. You need `memmove`.

So:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *get_number(void)
{
    char *sname = malloc(19);

    if (sname) strcpy(sname, "0x0012345678912345");
    return sname;
}

char *work_with_number(void)
{
    char *wnumber = get_number();

    if(strncmp(wnumber, "0x00", 4) == 0) {
        size_t len = strlen(wnumber + 4);       // length of rest of str

        memmove(wnumber, wnumber + 4, len);     // move rest to front
        wnumber[len++] = '7';                   // append digit seven
        wnumber[len++] = '\0';                  // append null terminator!
    }

    return wnumber;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *str = work_with_number();

    fprintf(stdout, "str : %s\n", str);         // user str
    free(str);                                  // free it after use

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution +1. I prefer `malloc(strlen("0x0012345678912345") + 1)` though. And the second `len++` is not really needed.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Last question ,what append if `7` must be calculated by and other function which accept a pointer as parameter and more especially `wnumber`. The pointer `wnumber` always contains 345 as three last digits and that could create and errror. Is there an equivalence to `memmove` which is zeroing the memory first ?

Comment: There's no need to zero anything as long as the range of valid characters is terminated by a zero. You can have a char buffer of size 100 that contains a null terminator followed by 99 garnage chars. That's a valid representation of the empty string. If you want to zero out the four bytes in the gap after the moved bytes, you can use `memset(str + len, 0, 4)`, but that's like cleaning and painting your ouse just before tearing it down.

Answer (score 4):

The problem, as I see it, are

- `malloc()` does not return null-initialzed memory blocks and `strcat()` expects the first argument to be null-terminated.
- You need to allocate memory for the null terminator also, if you want to use the array as *string*.

So,

1. Allocate space for holding null-terminator while allocating memory for `sname`.
2. Use `strcpy()` to copy the string into `sname`. Otherwise, you can call `calloc()` which returns 0-filled memory if you want to continue use of `strcat()`.
3. You can only call `free()` on the original pointer returned by `malloc()` and family. If you intend to move the actual pointer, you need to keep a copy of the original pointer somewhere to be passed to `free()` later.

Comment: Thank for you reliable answer, the main post has been exchanged according to your first note. However I am still confronted to the same issue on the second point `strcpy()` creates a memory dump.

Comment: @SnP you don't have enough room to concatenate anything to the original string.